# Opening existing microsoft word document in a particular page format

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I have a word document saved in A3 page format in user A machine.

Now when I send this document to User B  and he tries to open the document it should open in A4 page format. Presently it is opening in A3 format only which I do not want.
Want to know is there a way so that document opens in User B machine in A4 format only.

On User B machine the default is A4 only.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply save the document (or a copy) with size A4 on PC A, and then send that to PC B? That would be the simplest solution. If you absolutely must send an A3 document that will automatically resize itself to A4 on being opened, follow the steps below:

1. Save your document as a macro enabled .DOCM file.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor.
3. Under `Project (Document Name) / Microsoft Word Objects / ThisDocument` (see screenshot below for a file named **Test.docm**), enter the code shown:

   [image: 1]

   ```
   Private Sub Document_Open()
       ActiveDocument.PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperA4
   End Sub
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or `File / Close` to close the VBA editor.
5. Save the document and close Word.
6. Now as soon as you open the file the macro/VBA code will kick in and resize the document to A4. Obviously this will happen anywhere you open the file, including on PC A.

Comment: Thanks Karan this was really great to provide me this solution.

Comment: @Rahul: You're welcome, and if it helped you don't forget to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Install in B machine any A3 page postscript printer and set it default:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If need A1+ format install [HP Designjet Z6100ps 60in Photo PS3](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3338851&cc=br&taskId=135&prodSeriesId=3338748).